# MySQL ODBC - How to connect Access 2016 to remote server via SSH

Tags: mysql, linux, ms-access, ssh, putty

I have a Linux-based web server running with the LAMP package. For security reasons, the sever only allows logins via SSH and denies regular password login attempts. I want to use the MySQL ODBC driver within Microsoft Access 2016 to connect to this server for data analysis purposes, but I do not see an option in the ODBC Data Source configuration to add a source that works with SSH.

My question is, is there a way to configure the ODBC tool to work with SSH, or is there a tool that can bridge the gap? Thanks.

Additional Facts:

- The server runs Ubuntu Server 16.04.
- As far as I know, the server is listening to port 22 and 80 only.
- The local computer runs Windows 10.
- The computer can connect to the server terminal with PuTTY using private key SSH.
- The computer has MySQL Workbench that connects to the server's database with the same SSH authentication.
- I have the full suite of PuTTY tools installed, and some Googling around indicated that PLINK would be useful for a similar scenario, but I'm unsure how to go about that route (if PLINK is the answer, then a step-by-step answer would be much appreciated).
- Both the server and the computer are on the same local network 192.168.1.xxx.
- My end goal is to have linked tables in Access on my local machine that link to a particular MySQL database's tables on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **PuTTY**, in the left navigation panel, Go to **Connection > SSH > Tunnels**, add a new fowarded port(let's suppose your MySQL server is listening on **3306**):
[image: PuTTY - add a new fowarded port]

From now on, anything sent to localhost:3306 on your local computer will be forwarded to your MySQL server, it looks as if the MySQL server is installed on your local computer, happily coding!

Comment: In the ODBC setup, it's still giving me an error dialogue saying "Connection Failed [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.xxx (10061): ". Is the goal to make the ODBC think the server's MySQL is on the local machine by setting PuTTY to forward to 192.168.1.xxx and setting the ODBC target to be local? @Jerry Chin

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. In the picture above, I set the source port to 3306 and the destination to 127.0.0.1:3306. And in the ODBC setup, I set the hostname to 127.0.0.1 and the port to 3306, so Access thinks the database is local but it's being forwarded to my server. And also, I needed to have an SSH session open to allow the tunneling to work. It was just a matter of having the right IP settings. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You worked it out on your own, that's what matters most, nice done. I'll update the answer to reflect your efforts.