# Connection String for SQL Server Linked Server to MySQL via SSH

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssh

So far I used such a string for a linked server in SQL Server Express to connect to a MySQL database in the cloud:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ASV13_DB33968', @srvproduct=N'MySQL', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @provstr=N'Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver; Provider=MSDASQL; Server=real_Server_IP; Port=3306; DATABASE=db33968; USER=u33968; PASSWORD=myPW; OPTION=3', @catalog=N'db33968'
```

Now, the whole domain has SSH enabled and I spent days for connection again my linked Server.

I can't find a solution for that.

I have already set a tunnel by Putty which is open, but how is the linked server to be modified to connect??

I also tried to change to a ODBC connection by "Mysql ODBC driver" but this has no option for SSH, like "Devart ODBC driver", which is too expensive for private use.

I only managed to reach the MySQL database by Workbench, where you can define a TCP connection via SSH with all necessary inputs.

So, how can I reach that the SQL Server can connect to MySQL via SSH again?

Thanks!

Comment: why not run an external ssh client and keep the connection alive and connect via this tunnel

Comment: Please GUIDE me on that. Very much appreciated!!!

Comment: check the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-and-ssh.html

Comment: As far as I understood the manual, it needs to open the SSH tunnel by Putty (for example). This is done. But then again, it does not work when I set Server=localhost or 127.0.0.1  iso Server=real_server_IP. I do NOT understand, what server or server+port has to be set in the connection string. Please correct my string accordingly. I do not understand the issue with the port forwarding or maybe how to define the port forwarding in this string. Thx a lot

Comment: the fiirst time this is confusing but easy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058793/mysql-odbc-how-to-connect-access-2016-to-remote-server-via-ssh you can use the same configuration