# MySQL ODBC connector via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, odbc

Can the MySQL ODBC connector be connected to a MySQL server using ssh like in the MySQL workbench? A standard **working** connection `myConnection` to `my.server.com` via ssh in the workbench using the key `C:\user\keyfile.pem` looks as follows:

[MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ploEP.png)

But the ODBC connector's interface obtained from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) doesn't feature an option like "Standard TCP/IP over SSH":

[ODBC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysajc.png)

The reason for this is that i can't access this server without an ssh connection due to security reasons. The purpose is to connect MS Excel with the database on the server. An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058793/mysql-odbc-how-to-connect-access-2016-to-remote-server-via-ssh) seems to work with port-forwarding via puTTY and a similar question [here](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,577341,577341) has been left unanswered. Any suggestions?